# How to loop array inside of array in js?

Tags: javascript, json, frontend

i need to loop array from backend in js file to show some chart data. I need variable called `events` that contains array of data from backend. but from backend it comes as array too, so how i can loop it, so here's code, for better understanding

```
var events = [

    {
        id: 1,
        url: "",
        title: "TEST 1",
        start: "2023-02-12",
        extendedProps: {calendar: "Personal"}
    }, {
        id: 1,
        url: "",
        title: "TEST 1",
        start: "2023-02-12",
        extendedProps: {calendar: "ETC"}
    }, {
        id: 2,
        url: "",
        title: "Meeting With Client",
        start: "2023-02-12",
        extendedProps: {calendar: "Holiday"}
    }
];
```

I have more than 100 those kinds of data, so i need to loop them inside of array

Comment: need more clarification of what is it that you want. What do you get as data? what are your expected results? what have you tried so far?

Comment: i have data of array that includes info in the code above, like: id, url, title,

Comment: ok so that `var events` above is a sample of the data that you get right? you just want to loop thru it? or what kind of result do you expect to get?

Comment: where the array inside the array named `event` ? each elements are Objects !

Comment: yeah, I see only 1 array of objects

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if that's what you mean, but if you simply need to loop through your variable "events":

```
events.forEach(el => {
    console.log(el)
})
```

and if you need to loop through each object attribute:

```
events.forEach(el => {
    for(let i in el) {
        console.log(el[i])
    }
})
```

Is this what you needed?

Comment: no, look, see my code above in question part? so i have thoe kind of data say 500 and it all come from database, so i need that data exactly in  my example above